# How to add a segment between two nodes?

Tags: gimp

Using path tool, I created four nodes, then in edit mode I connected the first and fourth nodes, and then stroked the path. All worked well. I have a rectangle.

Now, I want to add a segment between first and third node, is it possible?

I tried creating a new path and stroke does not work on the new path.

Comment: Welcome sudheer! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, as was already said, you would want to add another line segment in the same path to "manually" connect the nodes.  The provided method involves creating a second path and them merging the two.  An easier solution is to simply find the relevant path in the path dialog, right click it, and select "Path Tool" from the context menu:

[image]

Then, click anywhere in a free area to start adding new nodes to the path, and drag them into position:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In path edit mode we can add another node by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **left-click** on the location we want it to be.

[image]

Note that this will convert the straight line to a curve. To make it straight lines again we have to drag the node's handles onto the node.

Comment: While correct, I don't  think this is what the O.P. is asking for at all - the request is to conenct the 1st and 3rd nodes (effectively having a Diagonal line).

Comment: @jsbueno: oooh - that may well be. In this case I believe it can't be done with the path tool from Gimp as it would instantaneously create a new path.

Comment: FYI, although this is not what the OP wanted, it could be noted that the handles can be reset into the node by [Ctrl] + [Shift] + left clicking on them.  This is a more precise way of removing any curvature from the path.

Comment: +1. This isn't what the OP wanted, but it is what *I* wanted when I searched for this question.

Comment: @AlexD: I am always happy when my answers help people - even after years :D

Comment: @jpheldson Thanks, I did not get the straight line working with the answer but it worked with your comment!

Answer (score 0):

'saul' on IRC helped.

To get the effect of connecting 1 and 3, create a new path, make the paths visible in the path dialog(just like in layer dialog), merge visible paths. Then all the visible paths are merged into one path.